# How to avoid "Position.includeScrollOffsets = true;"?

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous, prototypejs

I'm using scriptaculous to enable Drag&Drop (using Sortables) for components within a CMS. To ensure that even long component list (with scrolling) can be used without side-effects I had to set **Position.includeScrollOffsets = true;**. 
The problem is that other parts of the CMS (which I can't modify easily) break due to this setting. (Their calls to **Position.within(obj, this.mousePos.X, this.mousePos.Y)** return wrong values once the "includeScrollOffsets" is used)....

Is there any way to avoid this statement and still get the Sortables to work as supposed?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "Position.prepare();" right after the "Position.includeScrollOffsets = true;" did the job. - Hope this is a help for others ~~